# How to truncate a list item

Tags: jquery, html, css

How to truncate list items that is displayed inline.
Here is an example of the list.

```
<ul>
    <li>Some text1</li>
    <li>Some text2</li>
    <li>Some text3</li>
    <li>Some text4</li>
    <li>Some text5</li>
  <li>Some text6</li>
</ul>
```

To be completely displayed inline, the number of items in the list must the maximun 4. If the items in the list are more than 4, then truncation applies.
So if there are only 4 items in the list, it is displayed like

```
Some text1 Some text2 Some text3 Some text4
```

But if there are more than 4, like in the above case which has 6 items in the list. It is displayed this way

```
Some text1 ...  Some text5 Some text6
```

So that, items 2, 3,4 are hidden. Only onclick they are shown and displayed completely.

Comment: "Is it possible?" Yes. What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is possible, the logic is to identify the items you want hidden (maybe adding a class to them) and hide them via jquery. You can easily find code samples on each of those tasks individually. If you get stuck then come back with your effort, and people will help you fill in the blanks.

Comment: In which way are you using jQuery? Could you please show your JS code? Or do you mean by " Only on click they are shown. Is it possible?", the items are hidden in console? Please add further information to help you.

Comment: I am still thinking how to implement, if i need scripting or not.  As much as possible i want pure css.  I know how to truncate if it involves truncating the text content of the List item.  I just need the white-space:no-wrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis.  But in this case, i am thinking oj using jquery perhaps because of the onclick show.  L

Comment: Pure css will be hard because you want to hide a randon number of elements in between other elements, not elements at the end based on the overall length (which you might be able to pull off with overflow and text-overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's certainly possible to achieve this with a combination of CSS and JavaScript. What you want to do is limit the number of items displayed, and then check which elements should be truncated to ellipsis with [**modulo**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

This can be seen in the following example which uses jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var maxToShow = 3; // Number of links to show

  $("ul li").each(function(i, e) {
    if (maxToShow % i - 1) { // Truncate to ellipsis
      $(e).html('...');
    }
    if (i >= maxToShow) {
      $(e).hide(); // Hide additional items
    }
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0; /* Offset the default 40px <ul> padding */
}

li {
  display: inline-block; /* Display the elements inline */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Some text1</li>
  <li>Some text2</li>
  <li>Some text3</li>
  <li>Some text4</li>
  <li>Some text5</li>
  <li>Some text6</li>
</ul>
```

However, note that displaying list items inline kind of defeats the purpose of using list items, and you'd probably be better off using **[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** or similar.

---

#### EDIT:

To specifically show one at the start and two at the end, you'd be better off simply excluding the first `n` and last `n` elements from the truncation. This can be seen in the following:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Number to show
  var showAtStart = 1;
  var showAtEnd = 2;

  // Truncate to ellipsis
  for (var i = 0; i < $("ul li").length; i++) {
    if (i > showAtStart - 1 && i < $("ul li").length - showAtEnd) {
      $($("ul li")[i]).html('...');
    }
  }

});
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0; /* Offset the default 40px <ul> padding */
}

li {
  display: inline-block; /* Display the elements inline */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>Some text1</li>
  <li>Some text2</li>
  <li>Some text3</li>
  <li>Some text4</li>
  <li>Some text5</li>
  <li>Some text6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I will try to check your suggestion, and compare how to apply in my case.  I need to show the first child and the last two children. So perhaps i need to apply iteration. I will check.

Comment: @anni - I've edited my answer to showcase how you can do exactly that, and also easily change the start and end points. This will work regardless of how many elements there are :)

Comment: Your suggestion looks good. Still i need to check anyway.

Comment: It works, In my case even if i have extra class names for my styling.  I have a case before involving truncation where it does not work if i have a class name added.  But your solution is excellent, thanks!

Comment: Oh, i have just noticed your solution is not clickable to show the truncated list items, it purely truncates.